# Função retorna valor apenas a primeira vez que é executada

Tags: python-3.x

Este é o meu código:

```
import conector_modbus as conector_modbus
import leitor_csv as leitor_csv

address_file = 'address.csv'
dados = leitor_csv.leitor(address_file,"dicionario")

def coletar_dados():
    for dado in dados:
        if dado['var'] == "int":
            dado['valor'] = conector_modbus.ler_dado(int(dado['reg']),"int")
            yield dado
        if dado['var'] == "float":
            dado['valor'] = conector_modbus.ler_dado(int(dado['reg']),"float")
            yield dado

def preparar_dados(dados_modbus,maquina,num):
    registradores = {}
    for dado in dados_modbus:
        if dado['maquina'] == maquina and dado['num'] == num:
            registradores.update({dado['nome']:dado['valor']})
    return registradores


if conector_modbus.status_modbus("10.123.1.5",502) == True:
    dados_modbus = coletar_dados()
    dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    print(dados_br1)

    dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    print(dados_br1)
```

E este é o resultado:

```
root@jonatas-A530:/media/jonatas/Documentos/Projetos/orange_modbus# python3 teste.py
{'producao_ton': 1056.0025634765625, 'fluxo_ton_h': 0, 'corrente_amp': 32767, 'horimetro_h': 1064.68994140625, 'tempo_sob_carga_h': 4.1541666984558105, 'tempo_ocioso_h': 0.466552734375}
{}
```

A função foi chamada 2 vezes, mas na segunda ela não retorna valor. Gostaria de compreender porque isso ocorre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JonP, tenta fazer um loop na sua função coletar dados, pois nela você, faz um yield em dados, é com o yield sua função se torna  interavel, tendo a necessidade de interar nela para obter os dados. Tente isso:

```py
if conector_modbus.status_modbus("10.123.1.5",502) == True:
    dados_modbus = [ dados for dados in coletar_dados()]
    dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    print(dados_br1)

    dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    print(dados_br1)
```

Comment: Isso seria o mesmo que: dados_modbus = list(coletar_dados())?

Comment: Sim daria no mesmo.

Comment: Só para deixar registrado que ao converter um _generator_ para uma lista, você está carregando todo o conteúdo em memória. Se `coletar_dados()` retornar 10GB de dados, você estará colocando tudo em memória, e matando o propósito de usar _generators_.

Answer (score 2):

Sua função `coletar_dados()` é um `generator`, ou seja, depois que todos os dados forem consumidos seu propósito foi cumprido.

Para usá-lo novamente você precisa de outra instância do *generator*.

No seu caso basta criar um *generator* novo antes de usá-lo novamente.

```
if conector_modbus.status_modbus("10.123.1.5",502) == True:
    dados_modbus = coletar_dados()
    dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    print(dados_br1)

    dados_modbus = coletar_dados()  # criando outro generator
    dados_br1 = preparar_dados(dados_modbus,"br","1")
    print(dados_br1)
```

Comment: Olá Fernando, chamei novamente o a função coletar_dados() conforme sua dica, mas continuo recebendo o mesmo resultado, posso estar errando em algo mais?

Comment: Provavelmente seu `leitor_csv` também é um generator e precisa ser iniciado novamente. Como não sei o código desse módulo não posso dar certeza, mas é o mais provável.

Comment: Não existe uma forma de dar um "reset" no generator?

Comment: Basta chamar `leitor_csv.leitor(address_file,"dicionario")` novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Realizando uma pesquisa encontrei o seguinte [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python)

Uma das respostas foi a seguinte:

- Armazenar os resultados do generator, em uma estrutura de dados na
  memória ou disco  que você pode iterar novamente:

  ```
  dados_modbus = list(coletar_dados())
  for dado in dados_modbus: print(dado)
  for dado in dados_modbus: print(dado)`
  ```

Vou utilizar esta solução, apesar das outras sugestões anteriores estarem corretas também.

Comment: Só para deixar registrado que ao converter um _generator_ para uma lista, você está carregando todo o conteúdo em memória. Se `coletar_dados()` retornar 10GB de dados, você estará colocando tudo em memória, e matando o propósito de usar _generators_.